# Como carregar uma entidade Pais relacionada a Estado

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, repository

Estou começando no Entity Framework e ao tentar carregar uma entidade Estado, a entidade Pais relacianada está vindo com valor null, o que eu poderia ajustar no meu código para resolver?

**Classe Estado:**

```
public class Estado
{
   ...
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nome { get; set; }
   public Pais Pais { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Pais:**

```
public class Pais
{
   ...
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapeamento Estado:**

```
public class EstadoConfiguracao: EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoConfiguracao()
    {     
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Nome).HasColumnName("Nome").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        ToTable("estado");

        HasRequired(e => e.Pais).WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}
```

**Mapeamento Pais:**

```
public class PaisConfiguracao: EntityTypeConfiguration<Pais>
{
    public PaisConfiguracao()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Nome).HasColumnName("Nome").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        ToTable("pais");            
    }
}
```

Estou criando um método para receber o Id de um Estado como parâmetro e retornar o Estado com o Pais:

```
public Estado ObterComPais(Int32 id)
{
    return _context.Set<Estado>().Include(e => e.Pais).SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando exatamente o código da pergunta eu consegui.

É a primeira vez que uso [Toad for Mysql](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-mysql).

Percebi que tinha duas versões dele no PC: uma 7.3 outra 7.7 (e até então eu estava usando a mais antiga sem perceber).

Removi as tabelas e rodei meu script para recriar o BD porque eu estava achando muito estranho essa situação. Ao recriar o BD e agora usando Toad for Mysql na versão mais nova (7.7) consegui.

Então, com o código acima consegui carregar uma entidade Pais relacionada a Estado!

---

### Outra forma de mapear

Outra forma de mapear é adicionando uma propriedade em País, que representa uma coleção/lista de Estados que um País tem:

Classe Pais alterada:

```
public class Pais
{
   ...
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nome { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
}
```

Depois alterando o mapeamento de Estado:

```
public class EstadoConfiguracao: EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoConfiguracao()
    {     
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Nome).HasColumnName("Nome").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        ToTable("estado");

        HasRequired(e => e.Pais).WithMany(p => p.Estados).Map(m => m.MapKey("PaisId"));
    }
}
```

Assim, consegui mapear o relacionamento de **one-to-many**, onde um País tem muitos Estados.